# consuming webservice with c# from wsdl (noob)

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I am trying to write some c# code to call a web service.  I am trying to authenticate a user (authenticateToNCIDv2Request) and then see the result (authenticateToNCIDv2Result).  I do not understand, based on the wsdl, how to accomplish this.

My code (which is wrong) looks like:

```
SingleSignOn.authenticateToNCIDv2Request request = new SingleSignOn.authenticateToNCIDv2Request();
request.AppID = "1234";
request.AppPassword = "appPW";
request.UserID = "testUser";
request.UserPassword = "userPW";

request = new authenticateToNCIDv2Request1(request).authenticateToNCIDv2Request;

SingleSignOnTest.SingleSignOn.authenticateToNCIDv2Response resp = new SingleSignOn.authenticateToNCIDv2Response();
SingleSignOn.authenticateToNCIDv2Result rslt = resp.authenticateToNCIDv2Result;


string y = rslt.Error;
SingleSignOn.Message[] msg = rslt.MessageArray;
```

The wsdl (removed the parts that do not apply for brevity) is below:

```
<xs:element name="authenticateToNCIDv2Response" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:sequence xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:element ref="ncidng:authenticateToNCIDv2Result" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
 <xs:element name="authenticateToNCIDv2Result" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:sequence xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="ncidng:MessageArray" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Error" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="MessageArray" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:complexType xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:sequence xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="ncidng:Message" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
        </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Message" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> 
 <xs:complexType mixed="true" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:attribute name="code" type="xs:NMTOKEN" use="required" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/> 
  </xs:complexType> 
</xs:element>


<xs:group name="userinfogroup" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:sequence xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="User_DN" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="User_ID" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Personal_Title" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="First_Name" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Middle_Initial" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Last_Name" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Full_Name" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Suffix" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="User_Type" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Employee_Type" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="GUID" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Account_Expiration_Date" type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Login_Disabled" type="xs:boolean" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Locked_by_Intruder" type="xs:boolean" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Password_Expiration_Date" type="xs:dateTime" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Second_Factor_Role" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Account_Status" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Migration_Status" type="xs:boolean" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Business_Phone" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Business_Phone_Ext" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="eMail" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>           
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Street" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Address_Line2" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="City" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="State" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Zip_Code" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="CR_Config" type="xs:boolean" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>         
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="ncidng:Member_of_OrganizationArray" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="ncidng:Member_of_DivisionArray" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" ref="ncidng:Member_of_SectionArray" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>                               
        </xs:sequence>          
</xs:group>

<xs:element name="NCIDWebServiceException" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:sequence xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:element name="reason" nillable="true" type="xs:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>    
</xs:element>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are trying and not succeeding, is your rslt holding an error of some sort, or is your response getting an error from the http server?

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to do this? Traditionaly it's something like this

```
//initialize the client
SingleSignOn client = new SingleSignOnClient();
//initialize the request
authenticateToNCIDv2Request request = new authenticateToNCIDv2Request();
//fill the request
request.AppID = "1234";
request.AppPassword = "appPW";
request.UserID = "testUser";
request.UserPassword = "userPW";
//initialize the response and fill it with response from method
authenticateToNCIDv2Response response = client.authenticateToNCIDv2(request);
```

from here on you parse the response. Please beware that I did not take a deep look into your wsdl to see if my code is accurate

Comment: My main problem was that when I added the Service Reference I added the Service, and not the Service Contract (interface).  The answer from JSantos above was correct, and worked once I changed the Service Reference.  Thanks again J.

Comment: I'm glad that you got your problem fixed. Don't forget to close your question by choosing an answer